# How do I ensure a poor answer doesn't get bounty if it's the only answer?

Tags: support, bounties, not-an-answer, expired-bounty

I feel like someone made a comment as an answer on a question with a bounty just so they could reap the "auto bounty" since they are the only answer on it.

I've flagged the bad/useless answer (as a non-answer) for moderator review but the bounty will be assigned automatically in less than 24hrs and I feel like this guy/gal is just trying to cheat the system.

All I'm trying to do is ensure the bounty simply expires and the guy/gal that was trying to cheat the system by putting down a useless guess doesn't get it.

I've answered my own question (properly) and marked it as the accepted answer, not sure if that makes a difference though in this person still cheating the system since I'm the OP and created the accepted answer.

Here is the post: [Docker Private Registry - Deleted all images, but still showing in catalog](https://serverfault.com/questions/905065/docker-private-registry-deleted-all-images-but-still-showing-in-catalog)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as it's below +2 no automatic bounty will be awarded. If you're fine with the reputation going to /dev/null... Since that answer is at zero, you need do nothing. You cannot explicitly award the bounty to no one but here the answer has not met the minimum criteria

Answer (score 2):

Just a note, it's actually a common problem I see, where (usually new) users will post (crappy) answers to almost ending bounties with no other answers in hopes of getting the bounty.

As Journeyman mentioned, they need to **also** have a >2 score for the auto-bounty to kick in.

They obviously don't understand the auto-bounty system.

---

But all that's probably another issue to be discussed.

Comment: There was once a case where a user created a sock puppet to post an answer, awarded the bounty to that answer, and deleted the answer and sock puppet, in an edge case where the top-voted answer didn't work and he didn't want to award it the bounty.